# Marshal class, is there a way to find whether a data is already serialized or not?

Tags: ruby, serialization

I am using `Marshal` class to serialize a Ruby object, using the functions: `dump()` and `load()` everything works well, but when a value not related to any serialized data is passed, the `load()` function returns the expected and logical error:

```
incompatible marshal file format (can't be read)
format version 4.8 required; 45.45 given
```

What I need is to check if this data had already been serialized or not before loading it. My goal is to avoid this error and do something else.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe just rescue from the error?

```
begin
  Marshal.load("foobar")
rescue TypeError
  # not a marshalled object, do something else
  puts "warning: could not load ..."
end
```

Comment: Thank you Padde, i thought of this, but it is not useful for my case!
In fact i am working on a pre-existent data in a table, only when my code deals with a record that doesn't have the needed serialization i want to serialize an empty object and go a head to fill the new values by the user, "Rescue" takes me out of the instructions process!

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I've encountered very similar problem and, based on hints from this post http://lists.danga.com/pipermail/memcached/2007-December/006062.html,  I've figured out that this happens when you either try to load data that was not marshaled before *or* the data was stored improperly (e.g. not in binary field in database).

In my case specifically I used *text* type instead of *binary* field in database, and marshal data got mangled.

Changing type of column from text to binary helped. Unfortunately you cannot convert old (corrupted) data, so you have to drop the column and create it again as binary.

Answer (score -1):

I have applied Padde way, but using a function that does the job for me and get me back the object, either preexistent or new created as following:

```
def get_serialized_banner
  begin
    @banner_obj = Marshal.load(self.path)
  rescue TypeError
    self.path = Marshal.dump(Banner.new())
    self.save
    @banner_obj = Marshal.load(self.path)
  end
  return @banner_obj 
end
```